# How to fix alerts in server manager for Tile Data model server service?

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2016, windows-service

I manage a small collection of Windows Server 2016 Standard instances, virtualized on VMware and joined to an Active Directory domain. In Server Manager, I commonly see alerts on these servers for the "tiledatamodelsvc" having a status of Stopped.

My understanding is that this service backs Windows Live Tiles that can appear in the start menu. If I RDP into one of these servers, the service seems to wake up and the alert goes away. I don't know exactly what causes this alert to come back, but my guess is it would be after a long period with no interactive logons (none of these servers are used for RDS). Or, speculating, perhaps if I never RDP'd into a server at all after reboot there would be a different behavior?

Do I need to investigate further as to why this service gets stopped, or is this normal? And if so, what is the best practice for preventing this kind of alert? I believe I could set a GPO to disable this service, or I could use the GPO administrative template for Start Menu and Taskbar to "Turn off tile notifications", but as this is a User Configuration setting instead of a Computer Configuration one, I'm not sure that it would be applied.